# OANDA execution order REST API

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm trying to create a code to automatic execute orders in OANDA API

This is the code of my order:

```
class Execution(object):
    def __init__(self, domain, access_token, account_id):
        self.domain = domain
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.conn = self.obtain_connection()

def obtain_connection(self):
    return httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.domain)

def execute_order(self, instrument, units, order_type, side):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.access_token
    }
    params = urllib.urlencode({
        "instrument": instrument,
        "units": units,
        "type": order_type,
        "side": side
    })
    self.conn.request(
        "POST",
        "/v1/accounts/%s/orders" % str(self.account_id),
        params, headers
    )

    response = self.conn.getresponse().read()
    print response
```

When I try to execute the order I obtain a strange error that I'm not able to solve:

```
{"code" : 52,
"message" : "Invalid or malformed resource identifier: accountId",
"moreInfo" :    "http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/docs\/v1\/troubleshooting\/#errors"
}
```

Did someone ever face this kind of problem? I'm asking because in the tutorial of OANDA related to the errors (http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/troubleshooting-errors/) there is no mention about the code 52.

Is it a problem of connection or a problem about the creation of the order?

Comment: what is the http status code?

Answer (score 1):

I received that error several times, it was bugging me because I could not figure it out, both access token and account id were correct.  Then I realized I added the sub account AFTER creating my access token. You will be able to get historical prices because those are not account specific, but it wont let you in the account. So i had to revoke and regenerate my token, and it worked just fine. I know this is old, but I had this problem today.

Comment: Please expand on your answer - is it necessary to explicitly create an API subaccount to use any 3rd party software on OANDA?

Answer (score 0):

Although code 52 is not specified in the troubleshooting errors, I'm pretty sure you got a 400 status code from your request:

> 400   Bad Request Invalid or malformed argument: [arg]    The argument
>   specified is not properly formatted or is an unaccepted value

double check your `accountId`

http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/troubleshooting-errors/

please note that:

> "code" : [OANDA error code, may or may not be the same as the HTTP
>   status code],

Try "debugging" or passing your vars for the following section:

```
import requests
aTok = 'acess token'
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+aTok}
account_id = "your account id"
uri = 'https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com' #or non-practice api-fxtrade.oanda.com

resp = requests.get(uri+'/v1/accounts/{0}/orders'.format(account_id), headers=header)
response = resp.text
print(response)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes the status is 400 but still I don't know what the problem is. The account_id and access_token are correct because I'm able to perform a GET operation (I can retrieve the historical prices). 
As you said I think it could be a HTTP problem. I try to investigate in this way!

Comment: Are you using their REST API (I believe they have 2 diff. API's if I am not mistaken)

Comment: Yes I'm try to use the REST API! I'm still investigating about the problem.

Comment: see modified answer